# Why do I get an error when I query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I hope someone can help me:-)
Im trying to get some data from my mysql database which is hosted at simply.com

**I get this error, and simply cant understand why:**

Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta' at line 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/medieland/inc/connection.php on line 20

```
    //Connection to Database
try {
    $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "unable to connect to db which is the wordpress database";
    exit;
}

$results= $db->query('SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta');
$post_id = $results->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Not immediately apparent what should be wrong here. Maybe some “invisible” character made it into your code at this point, try and re-type the complete line that contains the SQL statement, to exclude that anything made its way in there via copy&paste or something.

Comment: Very good point.  Ill try that

Comment: You were right.   I retyped it all and it worked.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
as CBroe wrote, it was an "invisible" character.

I rewrote it all without copy/pasting anything, and it worked.

Here is the code:

```
    try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e;
}

try {
$sql="SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%start med at%' ORDER BY post_id DESC ";
$results=$db->query($sql);
$post_id = $results->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e;
}
var_dump($post_id);
```